# It is not possible to "delete" or "rename" a file in the SD card in the file explorer app

Tags: android, file, rename

My file Explorer app Internal storage is no problem, only SD card case is problem.

I'm making a file explorer app. This is the code to delete or rename a file in the SD card. There is no problem in internal storage, but a problem occurs when processing files on the SD card.
When i click Rename menu, "Couldn't Rename!" Only pop-ups occur.
When i delete a file, the file is not deleted.
Here, it is a function of the pop-up window when Rename and Delete is long-clicked on the file.

plz check my code:
.......................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

Mainfest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.files">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>

    <application
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_folder"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Files"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="com.pebble.intent.category.VR"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <provider
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_path">

            </meta-data>
        </provider>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Provider

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <external-path
        name="external"
        path="." />
    <external-files-path
        name="external_files"
        path="." />
    <cache-path
        name="cache"
        path="." />
    <external-cache-path
        name="external_cache"
        path="." />
    <files-path
        name="files"
        path="." />


    <root-path name="root" path="."/>

</paths>
```

Source Code

```
@Override
    public void onFileLongClicked(File file, int position) {

        final Dialog optionDialog = new Dialog(getContext());
        optionDialog.setContentView(R.layout.option_dialog);
        optionDialog.setTitle("Select Options.");
        ListView options =(ListView) optionDialog.findViewById(R.id.List);
        CustomAdapter customAdapter = new CustomAdapter();
        options.setAdapter(customAdapter);
        optionDialog.show();

        options.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                String selectItem = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();

                switch (selectItem){
                    
                    case "Rename":

                        AlertDialog.Builder renameDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
                        renameDialog.setTitle("Rename File:");
                        final EditText name = new EditText(getContext());
                        renameDialog.setView(name);

                        renameDialog.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                String new_name = name.getEditableText().toString();
                                String extention = file.getAbsolutePath().substring(file.getAbsolutePath().lastIndexOf("."));
                                File current = new File(file.getAbsolutePath());
                                File destination = new File(file.getAbsolutePath().replace(file.getName(), new_name) + extention);
                                if (current.renameTo(destination)){
                                    fileList.set(position, destination);
                                    fileAdapter.notifyItemChanged(position);
                                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Renamed!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                                else{
                                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Couldn't Rename!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            }
                        });

                        renameDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                optionDialog.cancel();
                            }
                        });
                        AlertDialog alertdialog_rename = renameDialog.create();
                        alertdialog_rename.show();

                        break;

                    case "Delete":
                        AlertDialog.Builder deleteDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
                        deleteDialog.setTitle("Delete" + file.getName() + "?");
                        deleteDialog.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                file.delete();
                                fileList.remove(position);
                                fileAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Deleted!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });

                        deleteDialog.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                optionDialog.cancel();
                            }
                        });

                        AlertDialog alertDialog_delete = deleteDialog.create();
                        alertDialog_delete.show();
                        break;

                  

                }
            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: What should your code do and what is the problem and question? And why that provider stuff?

Comment: `File current = new File(file.getAbsolutePath());` You mean : `File current = file;`.

Comment: `file.delete();` Better: `if(!file.delete()) return;`.

Comment: I want to change the file name (Rename) and delete the file as a function of the file explorer app.

Comment: The first time I asked a question, the method was clumsy. I added a little more explanation, can you take a look again?

Comment: You are still not checking the return value of file.delete() although i advised you to do so. Add a Toast too. And why that provider stuff?

Comment: `When i click Rename menu, "Couldn't Rename` That is your own message. Better: tell why you display that message.